# Who is the dead Heisenberg

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In episode S4E04 of Breaking Bad, Hank is helping another detective when he says something about a "dead Heisenberg" which messed his investigation.

So, who is this dead Heisenberg?

Comment: I'm trying to place the exact scene you're referring to. In S4E04 Hank has a conversation with Walt about Heisenberg, which he believes was Gale's name, who is now as "deader than a Texas salad bar".   I can't find a conversation with 'another detective'.

Comment: Tim Robert is his name. But you solved the question. Probably they're talking about fale.

Comment: Oh ok ... I think we've pieced this together.  This is S4E05.  I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a scene in S4E05 "Shotgun" where Hank is talking to [Tim Roberts](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Tim_Roberts) a detective at the Albuquerque Police Department:

> Hank: You know, uh, Tim, look, I appreciate what you're doing, really-- Uh, you know, keeping me involved and all, but, uh, you know, finding this guy Heisenberg dead like this I have to say, it, uh kind of feels like closure to me, you know?

They are talking about the investigation into the murder of [Gale Boetticher](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Gale_Boetticher), who was secretly working for Gus Fring, as assistant to Walter White.  The DEA are assuming that Gale is the mysterious Heisenberg .